# Methods for getting a const view of a container of smart pointers

Tags: c++

For a class that exposes a container of value types, const access to the members of the container is straightforward. For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class IntVecClass {
  public:
    IntVecClass() : fVec({1, 2, 3}) {}

    const std::vector<int>& getVector() const {
        return fVec;
    }

  private:
    std::vector<int> fVec;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    IntVecClass intVec;
    for (auto& elem : intVec.getVector()) {
        std::cout<< elem << std::endl;
        //elem = 1; FAILS TO COMPILE. GOOD!
    }
}
```

However, if the "int" is instead a "std::unique_ptr", although the std::unique_ptr is not modifiable by callers of getVector, the int that is contained in the std::unique_ptr is modifiable.

What are good ways of getting const views into a container of smart pointers? So far I've come up with using boost ranges and transforms:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

class PtrVecClass {
  public:
    PtrVecClass() : fVptr() {
        fVptr.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(1));
        fVptr.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(2));
        fVptr.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(3));
    }

    auto getRange() const {
        auto r = boost::make_iterator_range(std::cbegin(fVptr), std::cend(fVptr));
        return r | boost::adaptors::transformed([](const auto& elem) { return elem.get(); });
    }

  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> fVptr;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    PtrVecClass ptrVecClass;
    for (auto elem : ptrVecClass.getRange()) {
        std::cout<< *elem << std::endl;
        //*elem = 1; DOES COMPILE, BUT ALTERS THE CONTAINED INT.
    }
}
```

Comment: `elem = 1;` doesn't compile, since `elem` is an `int*`. And in fact `*elem = 1;` does change the original vector element's pointee.

Comment: @aschepler I have edited the question to correct that. Thank you.

Comment: So one way around this (without having propagate_const available), is to specify the return type of the lambda:

        return r | boost::adaptors::transformed([](const auto& elem) -> const int* { return elem.get(); });

Now the ints are const and cannot be modified.